# Conditional variance notation

Tags: variance, notation, conditional-variance

Why does the formula $\operatorname{Var} (Y\mid X)= E \left (\left(Y- E (Y\mid X)\right )^2\mid X\right )$ condition $EY$, but not $Y$, on $X$?

Comment: I don't understand the question, because by definition "$EY$" is a *number.*  What, then, do you mean by "condition $EY$" on anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It *does* condition $Y$ on $X$. But only *after* centering $Y$ around $E\left( Y \mid X \right)$.

$$\begin{align*}
\tilde Y &= \left( Y - E\left( Y \mid X = x \right) \right) ^2 \\
V(Y \mid X = x) &= E\left( \tilde Y \mid X = x \right)
\end{align*}$$

First we compute squared deviations of $Y$ itself around the conditional expectation. Then we compute the conditional expectation of those squared deviations.